# VTK: weird behavior vtkContourFilter

Tags: python, vtk

For my project, I have to display a 1D path in 3D space. For this I use a vtkContourFilter and following code:

```
import vtk

class Maze(object):
    """Representation of maze"""

    def __init__(self, filename):
        # read source data
        self.reader = vtk.vtkStructuredPointsReader()
        self.reader.SetFileName(filename)
        self.reader.Update()

        # map source data to object
        self.mapper = vtk.vtkDataSetMapper()
        self.mapper.SetInputConnection(self.reader.GetOutputPort())

        # create actor for object
        self.actor = vtk.vtkActor()
        self.actor.SetMapper(self.mapper)

class Path(object):
    """Representation of a path through the maze"""

    def __init__(self):
        # Point list
        self.points = []

        # data source
        self.vtk_points = vtk.vtkImageData()
        self.vtk_points.SetDimensions(100,100,100)
        info = self.vtk_points.GetInformation()
        self.vtk_points.SetPointDataActiveScalarInfo(info,vtk.VTK_UNSIGNED_SHORT,1)
        self.vtk_points.AllocateScalars()
        self.vtk_points.SetSpacing(1,1,1)  
        self.vtk_points.SetOrigin(0,0,0)

        # fill in data with 3D cube
        for x in xrange(1,10):
            for y in xrange(1,10):
                for z in xrange(1,10):
                    self.vtk_points.SetScalarComponentFromFloat(x,y,z,0,1)
        # fill in data with 1D line
        for x in xrange(1,100):
            self.vtk_points.SetScalarComponentFromFloat(x,x,x,0,1)

        # add filter
        self.contour_filter = vtk.vtkContourFilter()
        self.contour_filter.SetInput( self.vtk_points )
        self.contour_filter.SetValue( 10, 1 )

        # map source data to object
        self.mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
        self.mapper.SetInput( self.contour_filter.GetOutput() )

        # create actor for object
        self.actor = vtk.vtkActor()
        self.actor.SetMapper( self.mapper )


def create_renderer():
    renderer = vtk.vtkRenderer()
    renderer.SetBackground([0.5, 0.5, 0.5])
    return renderer

def create_window():
    window = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
    window.SetSize(1024, 768)
    return window

def create_interactor():
    interactor = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
    return interactor

def main():
    # Create/Init data sources (maze, mouse, text, ...)
    path = Path()
    maze = Maze("maze_2_values.vtk")

    # Request their actors
    path_actor = path.actor

    # Create renderer & add actors
    renderer = create_renderer()
    renderer.AddActor(path_actor)

    # Create window & add renderer
    window = create_window()
    window.AddRenderer(renderer)

    # Create interactor, add window & add observers
    interactor = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
    interactor.SetRenderWindow(window)

    # Start renderer & interactor
    window.Render()
    interactor.Initialize()
    interactor.Start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This generates the behavior that I want: The coutourfilter renders a cube and a diagonal. However, when I swap only 2 lines of code

```
path = Path()
maze = Maze("maze_2_values.vtk")
```

to

```
maze = Maze("maze_2_values.vtk")
path = Path()
```

the rendered results is completely different: Only the cube is shown (not the diagonal) and it's color is now blue instead of read. How is this possible? Both classes don't depend on eachother or share any resources. So I have no idea how swapping the order can have such a weird influence.